# Updating my record

Tags: php, mysql

Dear friend i am trying to update the recode but the following message always come up

" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9"

the code looks fine but i do not understand what i am doing wrong can someone help.
thanks in Advance.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
         // this id wil be pulled from the URL above. 
        $hot_id     = $_GET['hotl'];  
        $hotel_name = escape_value($_POST['title']);
        $hotel_star = escape_value($_POST['category']);
        $shortdes   = escape_value($_POST['shortdes']);
        $country    = escape_value($_POST['country']);
        $address    = escape_value($_POST['address']);
        $pcode      = escape_value($_POST['pcod']);
        $city       = escape_value($_POST['city']);         

        $query = "UPDATE Hotels SET  
                  hotel_name = '{$hotel_name}',
                  star ='{$hotel_star}',
                  description = '{$shortdes}',
                  country = '{$country}',
                  hotel_address = '{$address}',
                  hotel_postal_code = '{$pcode}',
                  hotel_city = '{$city}'
                  WHERE hotel_id = {$hot_id}";                
            $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

            if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){
            //Success
            }else{
            die("Some thing wrong with the Upadate: ". mysql_error());
            }

        }else{
        //error ocurred
        }
?>
```

i am posting my question in both PHP and Mysql Forum because i do not know exaectly where is the problem.

Comment: Show us the **generated** SQL.

Comment: Yeah, the error message tells you what is going wrong. Just fix the SQL and you're fine. You are probably in the need of parametrized queries which will make your problem disappear more easily. But you will need to say "bye bye mysql_* functions" then (which is not that hard ;) as you can see in the PHP manual )

Comment: as Matt says you should try echoing out the actual sql statement to see if its what you expext.  Also you should look at using prepared statements using mysqli or PDO rather than mysql_* statements.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to debug SQL statements (as mentioned above) is to echo out your query before you submit it and see exactly what you are sending to the database.  That being said, why don't you try putting some quotes(' ') around your $hot_id var:

`WHERE hotel_id = '{$hot_id}'`

Comment: @Salim Almughairi:) Echo the variable `$query` like this `echo $query;` and see what you get (and try to execute what you get on the terminal directly, may be phpmyadmin).

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere in the update there should be $hot_id:

```
"UPDATE Hotels SET  
    hotel_name = '{$hotel_name}', hotel_id = '{$hot_id}', etc
```